# Task.Delay() for 30 minutes (or longer periods) doesn't work as it should

Tags: c#, asynchronous, xamarin.forms, task, delay

In Xamarin I use the method Task.Delay() this way:

```
try{ 
    _myTask= Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(secondsToWait), 
    _someTokenForCancel);

     //some code..

     await _myTask;
}catch(TaskCanceledException e)
{
    //some code.. 
}
```

When secondsToWait is a small number (Lets say 600 for 10 minutes),
It is accurate.
When secondsToWait is a bigger number (Lets say 1800 for 30 minutes),
It is NOT accurate. It is done in latter time than it should.

Does someone have an idea what is the reason, and may recommend for using another function?
The demands are it to be asynchronously, and only one time (NOT an
event that needs to be activated every x seconds..)

Comment: I would assume that it is due to screen lock that you have probably set to 10 minutes.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "not accurate"?

Comment: What are the next lines in code after the "catch"? In other words: how do you determine whether the wait was "accurate"?

Comment: @IvanIčin  Hi, I tried it now. Set it to 20 seconds, I locked the phone, and it was ok, so I guess it is not the Screen Lock issue.

Comment: @StephenCleary HI, When I wrote "not accurate" I meant I suppose to hear a sound after amount of minutes, and when I set the time for an hour lets say, I will always hear the sound in delay of say few minutes (It's a lot).

Comment: @asaf92 Hi, after the catch there is a simple sound by this code:   _player.Load("applause.mp3");
            _player.Loop = true;

            if ((bool)App.Current.Properties["SoundKey"] == true)
                _player.Play();

            Task myTaskForPlayDelay = Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30));
            await myTaskForPlayDelay;

            _player.Pause();

Comment: A mobile application can be suspended so your simple delay won't work as expected (short delay might work, as the app does not suspend yet). Therefore, you should use platform specific API, such as https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgtaskscheduler for iOS.

Comment: @LexLi HI, The application is suspended also when I lock the phone (I checked whether OnSleep() method  is being called when I lock the phone - it is), and when I lock the phone - everything work well. The Task.delay() keep working, so I conclude it is not the suspension issue. Unless the suspension as result of locking is different from suspension as result of time passing?

Comment: Is this issue happend in Android as well? If you do some delay operation, you should do it with service.

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT Hi, I run it on an Android device, and develop with Xamarin, so as I see it, it happens in Android (Don't know about iOS). I'm sorry, I didn't understand the sentence "you should do it with service". Do you mean, there is another function you recommend to use?

Comment: It is android serivce like this thread https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/

Comment: @LeonLu-MSFT The article you linked to, is a specific article for Android. I develop in Xamarin. I've found somehting similar: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/android/app-fundamentals/services/creating-a-service/   do you think it supposed to solve the problem I displayed?

Comment: You can use dependence service to open a android service in xamarin forms.